# C - Using fscanf for reading hexadecimal and characters from files

Tags: c, formatting, scanf, xor

I have two files. The first file (in the pointer `key_file`) has the following content in hexadecimal (notice that every two characters corresponds to a hexadecimal byte):

```
18FC5E66F9F205488BFC0E9E
```

And the other file (in the pointer `p_text_file`) has the following content

```
hernandariov
```

I want to write the bitwise XOR between these two values and save the result in another file (in the pointer `c_text_file`). I write the following (abbreviated) code in C:

```c
char p_text_char;
unsigned char k_char;
for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    fscanf(key_file, "%2hhX", &k_char);
    fscanf(p_text_file, "%c", &p_text_char); 
    fprintf(c_text_file, "%02X", k_char ^ p_text_char);
}
```

But when I execute the code, it exits with a non-zero value, i.e, there is an error. After try many solutions, I found that if I change the type of `p_text_char` to `int`, the code works pretty well, but I want to know why. In fact, I want to keep `p_text_char` as `char` and `k_char` as `unsigned char` because these are the natural types and sizes for this variables in the problem I am working on (the one-time-pad encryption scheme). I am working on Windows with MinGw compiler.

Thank you.

**- EDIT -**

After run a debugger in this code, I found that there is a "segmentation fault". I try to minimize the code in order to find the error. First, I try the following code with the files as showed before:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 12

int main() {

    FILE *key_file;

    key_file = fopen("key.txt", "r");

    if(key_file == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot read the files.");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char k_char;
    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        fscanf(key_file, "%2hhX", &k_char);
    }

    fclose(key_file);
    return 0;
}
```

After one iteration of the for loop, the VS Code editor shows me a "segmentation fault". And when I change `k_char` to `int`, everything works fine. I will keep posting my findings about this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you have a crash? Have you tried running your program in a debugger? What does it tell you?

Comment: And have you remembered to check for errors? For example what do you think happen if a `fopen` call fails and you don't detect it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response @Someprogrammerdude, I will check it in a debugger, but I checked if the files are opened using conditionals asking for ```NULL``` pointers in each file. I think that is something related to variable types. I'll keep searching.

Comment: Start with using a debugger to see what's happening. If you can't figure it out yourself then please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and tell us when and where the crash happens in that program as well as the values of all involved variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, after the debugging I reduce my code to the "EDIT" section in the answer. VS Code debugger (using GDB) shows me a "segmentation error" I will keep searching for this bug. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of VS C that OP is using may [not understand `"%hhX"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-fields-scanf-and-wscanf-functions?view=vs-2019).  Formally this is *undefined behavior* and `*scanf()` may ignore `"hh"`.  Thus code "works" with an `int`.

To cope with C89-like compilers that lack `"hh"` understanding, use an intermediate object.

```
// fscanf(key_file, "%2hhX", &k_char);
unsigned utemp = 0;
fscanf(key_file, "%2X", &utemp);
k_char = utemp;
```

... or use a compiler that conforms at least to the 21 year old C99 standard, if not C11 or C17.  C2x due out in a year or two.